# Probability that point on line is closer to another point than either endpoint

Tags: probability

A point $A$, is chosen at random with uniform distribution on a line segment of length $L$. A second point, $B$, is chosen randomly, independently of the first. What is the probability that $B$ is closer to $A$ than to either of the endpoints of the segment?

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. I've set it up so the distance from the the beginning (call this point 0) to $B$ can be expressed as $B$, the distance from $L$ to $B$ can be expressed as $L-B$, and the distance between A and B is $|A-B|$, but I'm unsure of how to find the desired probability.

Comment: Hint: draw a plot a Cartesian plot with A and B as the axis, and shade in the area where B is closer to A than it is to either endpoints.

Comment: I suggest drawing a picture.

Comment: We can assume without loss of generality that $0<A<L/2$ since if that isn't the case, we can make it so by reflecting the selected point. After selecting A, points nearer to  A than either endpoint compose a continuous length of 2A. So given A, the probability is 2A/L. I'm not sure how to follow through though to get the overall probability.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed FYI the claim of $2A$ is wrong

Comment: Right! If its closer to 0 than A/2, then its closer to the endpoint than it is to A. The Satisfying points of B fall from A/2 to (1/2)(L-A)+A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the problem. Let the line segment be $[0,1]$ and suppose that $A=0.5$. Given this fixed $A$, what is the probability for a random $B$?

Now try it again for $A=0.6$ and $A=0.2$. Does the answer change? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: @theta If you add a picture to this answer, it will become immediately obvious.